# Is there a programmatic way to inspect the current rpath on Linux?

Tags: linux, rpath

I'm aware that it is possible to use `readelf -d <elf> | grep RPATH` to inspect a given binary from the shell, but is it possible to do this within a process?

Something like (my completely made up system call):

```
  /* get a copy of current rpath into buffer */
  sys_get_current_rpath(&buffer);
```

I'm trying to diagnose some suspect SO linking issues in our codebase, and would like to inspect the RPATH this way if possible (I'd rather not have to spawn an external script).

Comment: Keep in mind that when diagnosing shared library issues you should also inspect the RUNPATH tag. Thus you should `grep PATH` instead. It's up to the linker whether RPATH or RUNPATH is used, and there are subtle but important differences between the two: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52020177

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The question is specifically about `RPATH`, but modern linkers use `RUNPATH` instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47243544/50617) -- there is a subtle semantic difference between the two.

The answer is updated to print either.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <link.h>

int main()
{
  const ElfW(Dyn) *dyn = _DYNAMIC;
  const ElfW(Dyn) *rpath = NULL;
  const ElfW(Dyn) *runpath = NULL;
  const char *strtab = NULL;
  for (; dyn->d_tag != DT_NULL; ++dyn) {
    if (dyn->d_tag == DT_RPATH) {
      rpath = dyn;
    } else if (dyn->d_tag == DT_RUNPATH) {
      runpath = dyn;
    } else if (dyn->d_tag == DT_STRTAB) {
      strtab = (const char *)dyn->d_un.d_val;
    }
  }

  assert(strtab != NULL);

  if (rpath != NULL) {
    printf("RPATH: %s\n", strtab + rpath->d_un.d_val);
  } else if (runpath != NULL) {
    printf("RUNPATH: %s\n", strtab + runpath->d_un.d_val);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is brilliant, but it does not work with $ORIGIN. $ORIGIN is not interpreted, and returned as is by the function. Is there a way to add the $ORIGIN interpretation?

Comment: @Jérôme If you are executing in an environment where `/proc` is mounted, then expanding `$ORIGIN` is as simple as `readlink("/proc/self/exe", ...)` then NUL-terminate at the last slash.

Comment: While the question was specifically about `RPATH`, I'd like to note that it's equally important to check the `DT_RUNPATH` tag if one wishes to know the paths a binary might be loading its shared libraries from.

Answer (score 196):

For the record, here are a couple of commands that will show the `rpath` / `runpath` header.

```
objdump -x binary-or-library |grep 'R.*PATH'
```

Maybe an even better way to do it is the following:

```
readelf -d binary-or-library |head -20
```

The second command also lists the direct dependencies on other libraries followed by `rpath`.

Comment: On ubuntu 15.04 i have to use: objdump -x binary-or-library |grep RUNPATH

Comment: RPATH != RUNPATH, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967848/use-rpath-but-not-runpath & http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/10/28/rpath-and-runpath/

Comment: @AndreasRoth Fixed answer now to show both `RPATH` and `RUNPATH`.  It's better to set the latter as it has lesser priority than the env. variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`,  giving  more flexibility to user.

Answer (score 21):

You can also use:

```
chrpath -l binary-or-library
```

Comment: On ubuntu: `apt-get install -y chrpath`

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I use for convenience, as a shell function:

```
function getrpath {
    eu-readelf -d "${1:?}" | sed -e '/RUNPATH/{s~.*\[\(.*\)\]~\1~;n};d'
}
```

This consumes `eu-readelf` output from `elfutils` like:

```
Type              Value
NEEDED            Shared library: [libpq.so.5]
NEEDED            Shared library: [libc.so.6]
RUNPATH           Library runpath: [/some/path/to/lib]
....
```

and emits

```
 /some/path/to/lib
```

It should work fine with binutils `readelf` instead of elfutils `eu-readelf` too.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [patchelf](https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf) it can also print rpath in a pretty format:

```
> patchelf --print-rpath /path/to/elf
$ORIGIN:$ORIGIN/../../lib
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way.  Follow the example code in `man dlinfo` [1], but use `NULL` as the first parameter of `dlopen()`.

[1] https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlinfo.3.html