# Get RPATH of current process on OSX

Tags: c, macos, rpath

Essentially, I am looking for an answer to this question: [Is there a way to inspect the current rpath on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836330/is-there-a-way-to-inspect-the-current-rpath-on-linux), but for OSX.
I want to programmatically get the RPATH entries for the current process in OSX.  I know how to do this using the shell, but I'm looking for a method to internally inspect my process.

Thank you!