# How do I resolve "library not found for -lgfortran" when compiling a Rust application on macOS?

Tags: rust, gfortran

I am trying to build a Rust app and I get the below when trying to build.  This happened after I installed ndarray-linalg and ndarray.

I installed gcc and openvc.  I am on macOS.

```
 = note: ld: library not found for -lgfortran
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I resolve this?

```
which gfortran
/usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

I found the library here:

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/libgfortran.*
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/libgfortran.5.dylib    
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/libgfortran.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/libgfortran.a      
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/libgfortran.spec
```

```
ldconfig -p | grep fortran
-bash: ldconfig: command not found
```

And also ran the below:

```
brew reinstall gcc
```

How can I make sure Rust will find it?

Comment: binary != library

Comment: The linker is looking for the libgfortran library, not the gfortran executable.

Comment: (I hope this works on mac as well) type `ldconfig -p | grep fortran` and put it into your question please.

Comment: @hellow I added

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Linking Rust application with a dynamic library not in the runtime linker search path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40602708/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking Rust application with a dynamic library not in the runtime linker search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602708/linking-rust-application-with-a-dynamic-library-not-in-the-runtime-linker-search)

Answer (score 0):

Check first if any of the env variables are set

- **DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH**
- **DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH**

These variables tell the compiler where to look for libraries installed on the system. Built-in libraries are usually placed in `/usr/lib`, and *homebrew* places them in `/usr/local/lib`. So these should be in your lib path.

If for some reason you cant find your library there you can try

```
export DYLD_LIBARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8
```

and if that does not work try with the other variables.