# compilation failed for package ‘ccgarch’ in R

Tags: r

I am using R 3.6.3 on my Mac (Big Sur, V11.2) and trying to install the package "CCGarch" via zip file for my finance project. The installation of the package is throwing an error which i have no clue how to resolve. I am posting the error message below and would really appreciate a resolution for that:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ccgarch.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ccgarch’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/ccgarch’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/roshni/Desktop/IIM KASHIPUR copy/Academics/Term V/FRMM/R update/ccgarch_0.2.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Your version of R is quite old now. What if you update R and try again?

Comment: Do you have gcc-libs installed? Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139004/how-do-i-resolve-library-not-found-for-lgfortran-when-compiling-a-rust-applic?rq=1)

Comment: @Phil `ccgarch` was archived on CRAN on 2019-03-05 and its latest version was released in 2014, that's a lot older than R 3.6.3 (2020-02-29), so that being the issue is quite unlikely.

Comment: @ChrisHaug Fair.