# SQLAPI++: Get path to shared library loaded by executable

Tags: ld, dynamic-linking, sqlapi++, tdsodbc

SQLAPI++ has an unusual feature where you set a string to tell it where to find the ODBC shared library.  In my case this is `libtdsodbc.so`, and my application actually links that library at build time, but at runtime this is not enough for SQLAPI++ to work.

My code is:

```
  SAConnection conn;
  conn.setOption("ODBC.LIBS") = "libtdsodbc.so";
  conn.Connect("SERVER=...", "", "", SA_ODBC_Client);
```

`ODBC.LIBS` is [documented](http://www.sqlapi.com/ServerSpecific/ODBC.html) like this:

> Forces SQLAPI++ Library to use specified ODBC manager library.

The above code works if you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to a directory containing `libtdsodbc.so`.  But if you don't, `Connect()` fails:

```
libtdsodbc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

DBMS API Library 'libtdsodbc.so' loading fails
This library is a part of DBMS client installation, not SQLAPI++
Make sure DBMS client is installed and
this required library is available for dynamic loading

Linux/Unix:
1) The directories in the user's LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable
2) The list of libraries cached in /etc/ld.so.cache
3) /usr/lib, followed by /lib
```

It works again if you set `ODBC.LIBS` to a full path rather than just a filename.  But how can the application know which path?

My application (outside of SQLAPI++) finds `libtdsodbc.so` via its `RUNPATH` which is set at build time.  This path is not a system path like `/usr/lib`.  I'd like to have SQLAPI++ use the same library which is loaded in the application at runtime.

One idea is for the application to [inspect its own `RUNPATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846736/4323), search for `libtdsobc.so`, and use that path.  But this requires quite a bit of fiddly code to basically reimplement what `ld.so` already does.

I don't want to bake the path into the executable at build time separately from `RUNPATH`, because I sometimes edit `RUNPATH` before deployment (and then I'd need to edit two things).

Ideally I would like to tell SQLAPI++ to just use the library which is already loaded.  I can figure this path out by running `lsof -p PID | grep libtdsodbc.so` but running shell commands from within the executable is not a good solution (and again I would rather not reimplement `lsof`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use [dl_iterate_phdr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr) (the link also includes a sample code which prints out lib names) or manually parse `/proc/self/maps`.