# Dynamic linking with rpath not working under Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: r, makefile, g++, rcpp, dynamic-linking

I build an R package which uses Rcpp and links to a third-party shared object (`libbarraopt.so`) (which also links to other shared objects such as `liboptsrvr.so` in its own directory). To ensure that it is able to find those shared objects it links against, I put the following variables in `~/.Renviron`:

```
BARRA_OPS_HOME=${HOME}/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5
```

In the package, I create the following `src/Makevars`:

```
BARRA_LIB=$(BARRA_OPS_HOME)/lib/intel64
BARRA_INCLUDE=$(BARRA_OPS_HOME)/include
PKG_CXXFLAGS=-I$(BARRA_INCLUDE)
PKG_CFLAGS=-I$(BARRA_INCLUDE)
PKG_LIBS=-L$(BARRA_LIB) -Wl,-R,$(BARRA_LIB) -lbarraopt
```

Under Ubuntu 16.04, I can build, load, and use the package successfully without any problem. However, when I test exactly the same package when OS is upgraded to 17.10, the package can be built but it cannot be loaded, saying:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/renkun/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -I/home/renkun/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/renkun/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"   -I/home/renkun/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -c barraopt.cpp -o barraopt.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o barraopt.so RcppExports.o barraopt.o -L/home/renkun/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64 -Wl,-R,/home/renkun/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64 -lbarraopt -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /tmp/Rtmpvbb6Io/devtools_install_42a342a07f84/barraopt/libs
* DONE (barraopt)
Error in dyn.load(dllfile) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/renkun/Workspaces/barraopt/src/barraopt.so':
  liboptsrvr.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... <Anonymous> -> load_all -> load_dll -> library.dynam2 -> dyn.load
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

It seems that `-Wl,-rpath` is not effective here.

Under a machine with Ubuntu 16.04, `ldd src/barraopt.so` shows that all dynamic linking is corrected resolved. (`BARRA_OPS_HOME = /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5`)

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc89a16000)
libbarraopt.so => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libbarraopt.so (0x00007f85dae49000)
libimf.so => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libimf.so (0x00007f85da97f000)
libR.so => /usr/lib/libR.so (0x00007f85da346000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f85d9fc4000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f85d9dae000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f85d99e3000)
liboptsrvr.so => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/liboptsrvr.so (0x00007f85d7b10000)
libopsproto.so => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libopsproto.so (0x00007f85d77a1000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f85d7497000)
libintlc.so.5 => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libintlc.so.5 (0x00007f85d7249000)
libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0x00007f85d6fe8000)
libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007f85d6da1000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f85d6b31000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f85d690f000)
libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f85d66fe000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f85d64e4000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f85d62dc000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f85d60d7000)
libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f85d5eb5000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f85d5c98000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055fb75088000)
libifcore.so.5 => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libifcore.so.5 (0x00007f85d5961000)
libifport.so.5 => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libifport.so.5 (0x00007f85d5732000)
libsvml.so => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libsvml.so (0x00007f85d4e6d000)
libmosek64.so.7.0 => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libmosek64.so.7.0 (0x00007f85d3c63000)
libiomp5.so => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so (0x00007f85d396b000)
libprotobuf.so.6 => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libprotobuf.so.6 (0x00007f85d3668000)
libbridge_common.so => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libbridge_common.so (0x00007f85d3417000)
libsharc_xmlxproto.so => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libsharc_xmlxproto.so (0x00007f85d31a4000)
libboost_thread.so.1.49.0 => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libboost_thread.so.1.49.0 (0x00007f85d2f8a000)
libopenblas.so.0 => /usr/lib/libopenblas.so.0 (0x00007f85d0ef5000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f85d0ccc000)
libxerces-c-3.1.so => /home/ken/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libxerces-c-3.1.so (0x00007f85d07c4000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f85d0499000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f85d027f000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f85d0040000)
```

However, with the same source, under Ubuntu 17.10, `ldd` shows that  the shared objects `libbarraopt.so` links against are not resolved even though `-Wl,-rpath` is secified: (`BARRA_OPS_HOME = /home/renkun/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5`)

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe067f5000)
libbarraopt.so => /home/renkun/bin/BarraOptimizer8.5/lib/intel64/libbarraopt.so (0x00007f3dc5f0c000)
libR.so => /usr/lib/libR.so (0x00007f3dc58e4000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3dc555e000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3dc5208000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3dc4ff1000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3dc4c11000)
liboptsrvr.so => not found
libopsproto.so => not found
libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3 (0x00007f3dc49b6000)
libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007f3dc4770000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f3dc44fe000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f3dc42d8000)
libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f3dc40c8000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f3dc3eab000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f3dc3ca3000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3dc3a9f000)
libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f3dc3870000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3dc3651000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3dc6526000)
libopenblas.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.so.0 (0x00007f3dc13ab000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f3dc1182000)
libgfortran.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.4 (0x00007f3dc0da3000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f3dc0b63000)
```

It looks like only `libbarraopt.so` is linked with the correct path but shared objects it links against are missing.

I'm wondering what might be wrong with my build configurations that breaks under the toolchain shipped by 17.10. Although using global config such as `ldconfig` would solve such problem, I prefer not because some `.so` it relies have conflict with the version the OS ships. I'd rather use a locally configured version without affecting the global config.

Comment: Well just got home ... but let me assure you that just this week I set a new project up with `-rpath` under 17.04 and it worked as expected...  A more minimal example may reduce the barrier to helping you here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> It seems that -Wl,-rpath is not effective here.

What likely happened is that your updated linker emits `DT_RUNPATH` dynamic tag, where the old linker emitted `DT_RPATH`. (It's also possible that your old linker was GNU-ld, and the new one is Gold.)

The `DT_RUNPATH` is preferred as more correct, and affects search path of the binary itself, but not of any of the dependent libraries.

The `DT_RPATH` has global effect, similar to adding the directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

You can verify this with: `readelf -d a.out | grep 'R.*PATH'`.

If you do see the `RPATH` vs. `RUNPATH` difference, and in fact are using Gold, you can force the "old" behavior with `-Wl,--disable-new-dtags` (`GNU ld` also had `--disable-new-dtags` added to it recently, so it should work for either linker).

Comment: Yes, `RUNPATH` instead of `RPATH` appear in ELF. In my case, `RPATH` is what I need.

Comment: Looks like the default behavior of `ld` shipped with Ubuntu 16.04 is different from that with Ubuntu 17.10. I look at both locations that `/usr/bin/ld` points to, they both point to `x86_64-linux-gnu-ld` but with different version. Is one `GNU-ld` and the other `Gold` or just version breaking?

Comment: @KunRen I don't have easy access to either `16.04` of `17.10`. You can run `ld --version`. GNU-ld will look like this: `GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) ...`. Gold will look like this: `GNU gold (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu ...)`

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04: GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
Ubuntu 17.10: GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.29.1

Comment: @KunRen It's also possible that GCC invokes something other than `/usr/bin/ld` (i.e. GCC on `17.10` may be configured to invoke Gold). Use `gcc --print-prog-name=ld` to find out.

Comment: @EmployedRussian you closed my question as a dup of this. I don't get *any* results from `readelf` for `DT_R.*PATH` (I do get `RUNPATH` by itself)

Comment: @SteveLorimer Right. `DT_` is not part of the output. Answer corrected.

Comment: @EmployedRussian thanks! I have tested on both Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10 and `-Wl,--disable-new-dtags` flag has fixed my problem.

Comment: @EmployedRussian the comments at the bottom of [this blog post](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/10/28/rpath-and-runpath/) mention **`DT_RPATH` is considered a flaw in the ELF specification**. How does one propagate the `RUNPATH` to transitive dependencies? Is the *"fix"* to set `RUNPATH` on the dependencies themselves? Is there a better way? TIA.

Comment: @SteveLorimer Yes: the idea is that every ELF image should be built to correctly describe its own required runtime paths and its own dependencies, rather than depending on which "main" application it is loaded into. Setting `RUNPATH` on each of the transitive dependencies is a way to achieve that.

Comment: How can I get ld to embed RPATH and not RUNPATH? This would be a quick solution for a similar issue I'm dealing with until I can get around to migrate all my build to the C++ 11 linkage convention and eliminate much of the complexity.

Comment: @EmployedRussian - I couldn't find any suggestion as to how can I get ld to embed RPATH and not RUNPATH. I might be missing something here, but I'd appreciate a clearer pointer.

Comment: @YitzikC Use `-Wl,--disable-new-dtags` flag.