# Shared library not found - not in NEEDED section but indirect dependency

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries

I have an executable that links against a dynamic library (called `libester_timing.so`), which in turn links against another shared library (`libester_patternset.so`). Yet my executable only uses parts of `libester_timing.so`, which do not rely on `libester_patternset.so`. Thus, `libester_patternset.so` is not part of the NEEDED section in the ELF dynamic section of my executable:

```
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdate_tools.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libester_timing.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libester_circuit.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libester_bitlogic.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libester_utilities.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_system.so.1.65.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_filesystem.so.1.65.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.65.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_log.so.1.65.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Correspondingly, `ldd` gives me:

```
libester_patternset.so => not found
```

Note that all `libester_*` libraries are located in the same folder (which is not in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) and for all NEEDED libraries, `ldd` returns that folder correctly.

Now if I call my executable, I get the **"cannot open shared object file"** error. This problem vanishes if I insert code into my executable, which calls functions from the `libester_patternset.so` library (even if the code is never executed).

My understanding (for now) is that the loader loads `libester_timing.so`, which requires `libester_patternset.so`, but now does not use the `RUNPATH` (or `RPATH`) of the executable anymore, but uses `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead - indeed the problem vanishes if I modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correspondingly. Is that correct? How can I circumvent this problem? Both solutions (adding unnecessary code or adjusting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) seem very **"hacky"** to me at best. Do I need to modify `libester_timing.so`'s `RPATH`?

Comment: Your understanding is correct but instead of answering your question directly I suggest you `+1` [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47243544/2170527) excellent answer.

Comment: Yes that worked! It is indeed a duplicate, sorry for missing this.

Comment: Np, it may indeed be hard to find existing questions.