# Embed RPATH instead of RUNPATH in when building shared-objects on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: g++, ld, dynamic-linking, ubuntu-18.04, rpath

I have a Linux shared-object, which links dynamically with some shared-objects, and some of them in turn link dynamically further with additional shared-objects, requiring *indirect dynamic linking*. To find those SOs I embed an RPATH header into my top-level SO by passing linker flags to G++ as in:

```
 -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker $ORIGIN/../my/libs
```

This works on both Ubuntu 16.04 and CentOS 7.x (with G++ 7.3 from DevToolset 7). However, when performing this build on Ubuntu 18.04, it embeds a RUNPATH header instead. Unlike RPATH, RUNPATH is only considered for finding SOs required by my top-level SO, but not for *indirect dynamic linking* of subsequent SOs that they require.

I've confirmed that the change from RPATH to RUNPATH causes the issue. When I use an SO built on Ubuntu 16.04, that has an RPATH header, indirect linking works properly. When I change the RPATH header to a RUNPATH header using *chrpath -c*, indirect linking breaks, on both Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 16.04.

How can I get the linker to use RPATH on Ubuntu 18.04? Alternatively, how can I accomplish the inverse of *chrpath -c* - change a RUNPATH header into an RPATH?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic linking with rpath not working under Ubuntu 17.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117443/dynamic-linking-with-rpath-not-working-under-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: @EmployedRussian - I've narrowed the scope of the question to only deal with creating an RPATH header.

Comment: Wow, this _question_ answers the problem I have (I was wondering about the difference of the indirect links based on the expirience, but was not able to find any info on it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I get RUNPATH to be passed down to subsequent SOs during indirect linking?

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47243544/50617), you can't.

The best approach is to fix all libraries to be self-sufficient (have their own correct `RUNPATH`).

If you can't do that, use `RPATH` instead of `RUNPATH`, by adding `-Wl,--disable-new-dtags` to the link line.