# Part of OpenCV libraries are not found during dynamic linking

Tags: opencv, linker

I have a program using OpenCV. I link the library using `-L/path/to/opencv/lib` flags, and also the path to the library is specified using `-Wl,-rpath` flag.

For some reason, when running `ldd`, I see that the links to most of the OpenCV libraries are found(for example opencv_core). However, all the CUDA related libraries(such as opencv_cudaarithm) are not found.

This was fixed when I have added the OpenCV library path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but I would have expected it to work without having to change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, especially since the path to some of the libraries is resolved.

Does anyone have an idea what it could be?

**Edit:**
There is no error message
The output from `ldd` before adding OpenCV to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4 => /usr/Local/opencv/v.3.4.13/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4 (0x00007fcf7acd4000)
libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 => /usr/Local/opencv/v.3.4.13/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 (0x00007fcf7918e000)
libopencv_core.so.3.4 => /usr/Local/opencv/v.3.4.13/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4 (0x00007fcf77fb0000)
libopencv_photo.so.3.4 => /usr/Local/opencv/v.3.4.13/lib/libopencv_photo.so.3.4 (0x00007fcf77dfe000)
libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.3.4 => not found
libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.4 => not found
```

After adding OpenCV:

```
libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4 => /usr/Local/opencv/v.3.4.13/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4 (0x00007fcf7acd4000)
libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 => /usr/Local/opencv/v.3.4.13/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 (0x00007fcf7918e000)
libopencv_core.so.3.4 => /usr/Local/opencv/v.3.4.13/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4 (0x00007fcf77fb0000)
libopencv_photo.so.3.4 => /usr/Local/opencv/v.3.4.13/lib/libopencv_photo.so.3.4 (0x00007fcf77dfe000)
libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.3.4 => /usr/Local/opencv/v.3.4.13/lib/libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.3.4 (0x00007fcf76b03000)
libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.4 => /usr/Local/opencv/v.3.4.13/lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so.3.4 (0x00007fcf74bed000)
```

Comment: Showing the _actual_ link line, the error message, and the output from `ldd` (with and without setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) would probably help giving you correct answer. I _suspect_ I know the answer, but don't want to speculate without additional info.

Comment: I've added the output as an edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47243544/50617) explains, using `-rpath=...` only affects the direct dependencies from the main executable, but not *transitive* dependencies from one DSO on another.

You could fix this issue in one of two ways:

1. Add `-Wl,--disable-new-dtags` to your link line. That should change `DT_RUNPATH` to `DT_RPATH` (use `readelf -d your-exe` to confirm), which would make the `-rpath` setting have a global effect.
2. Add *direct* dependencies on `libopencv_cudaimgproc` and `libopencv_cudaarithm` to the executable itself, by adding `-lopencv_cudaarithm -lopencv_cudaimgproc` to your link line. (You may have to also add `-Wl,--no-as-needed` before them if your GCC is configured to pass `-Wl,--as-needed` to the linker by default).