# Finding the rendezvous (struct r_debug) structure of a process?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, elf, debug-symbols

I'm trying to access the "rendezvous structure" (struct r_debug *)
in order to find the link map of a process.
But I keep running into invalid adresses and I really can't figure out
what's going on.

Here's how I go on trying to find it:

```
1. Get the AT_PHDR value from the auxiliary vector
2. Go through the program headers until I find the PT_DYNAMIC segment
3. Try to access the vaddr of that segment (PT_DYNAMIC) to get the dynamic tags
4. Iterate through the dynamic tags until I find DT_DEBUG. If I get here I should be done
```

The issue is I can't get past step 3 because the vaddr of the PT_DYNAMIC
segment always points to an invalid address.

What am I doing wrong ? Do I need to find the relocation of the vaddr ?
I have looked at the LLDB sources but I can't figure out how they got the address.

UPDATE: @EmployedRussian was right, I was looking at a position-independent executable.
His solution to calculate the relocation worked wonderfully.

Comment: I believe including a snippet of your code and the error messages you got will help improve the question a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong ?

Most likely you are looking at position-independent executable. If your `readelf -Wl a.out` looks like this:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0001f8 0x0001f8 R   0x8
  INTERP         0x000238 0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000000238 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x016d28 0x016d28 R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x017250 0x0000000000217250 0x0000000000217250 0x0010d0 0x001290 RW  0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x017df8 0x0000000000217df8 0x0000000000217df8 0x0001e0 0x0001e0 RW  0x8
```

then you need to adjust `Phdr_pt_dynamic.p_vaddr` by the executable relocation address (the key is that the first `Phdr_pt_load.p_vaddr == 0`).

You can find this relocation address as the delta between `AT_PHDR` value in the aux vector and `Phdr_pt_phdr.p_vaddr`.

(Above I use `Phdr_xxx` as a shorthand for `Phdr[j]` with `.p_type == xxx`).

You are also doing it in much more complicated way than you have to: the address of the dynamic array is trivially available as `_DYNAMIC[]`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846736/50617).

Comment: I can't use _DYNAMIC because I am getting the dynamic array from a remote process.